# Compare two XML files preferably using Python

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I need to compare two XML files having same structure for any extra lines. Below example provides some details:

File 1:

```
<Log1> Some text here </Log1>
<Log2>
      <Id1> Some text here </Id1>
      <Id2> Some text here </Id2>
</Log2>
```

File2:

```
<Log1> Some text here </Log1>
<Log2>
      <Id1> Some text here </Id1>
      <Id2> Some text here </Id2>
</Log2>
<Log3> Some text here </Log3>
```

I need the diff to identify here that there is one extra tag in File2. Is there an efficient to do this in Python?

Comment: Show us your code thus far.

Comment: These aren't XML files. XML files always have a containing outermost element.

Comment: You need to expand on the requirement. What is the program to do if there are other differences between the files, eg. extra lines somewhere other than at the end, or different tags, or different whitespace?